# Workout to prolong erection?

Tags: workout, endurance, sex

I just want to know if it is possible to prolong an erection with the help of workouts. Are there any specific exercises that can be done to help with this?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because nope, nope, nope, no way. http://31.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m7k59i7Ryd1rwcc6bo1_250.gif

Comment: I removed the kindergarten giggly speech and some unnecessary information, I see this as a valid question.

Comment: I voted to close also, not sure how this got so many upvotes. From the help section on what can I ask, as part of "what CAN'T I ask" - "wellness, general health, medical advice and injuries unrelated to exercise". Simply saying "by working out" does not make it exercise related.

Comment: Why is this any different than asking "which exercise should I perform do enhance my chest?", I think this questions does indeed fall under the scope of the site.

Comment: Obviously from the split decisions, it's on the edge of validity. I could see a case for it either way, maybe better suited for a chat or meta discussion.

Comment: Very probably, this question is related to increasing endogenous testosterone levels naturally, which is a very common concern in bodybuilding. I think it is on-topic. If not, please tell me why these other questions are OK while OP's shouldn't be: "Workout to loose fat?", "Workout to increase aerobic endurance?", "Workout to prolong isometric resistance to a fixed weight?". What is the difference here?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

While the penis itself isn't a muscle that can be trained, but simply speaking just a sponge for blood, there are three muscles that are responsible for supporting ejaculation and maintaining an erection via compression of blood vessels.

[Musculus retractor penis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retractor_muscle_of_the_penis)
It doesn't seem like this muscle is important in humans, the english wikipedia article doesn't tell much nor does the german version. It still exists in humans.

[Bulbospongiosus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulbospongiosus_muscle):

> In males it contributes to erection, ejaculation, and the feelings of orgasm.

[Ischiocavernosus muscle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ischiocavernosus_muscle):

> It helps flex the anus, and (in males) stabilize the erect penis or (in females) tense the vagina during orgasm. Kegel exercises (also known as pelvic floor exercises) can help tone the ischiocavernosus muscle.
>
> Ischiocavernosus compresses the crus penis, and retards the return of the blood through the veins, and thus serves to maintain the organ erect.

And there you have it, **pelvic floor exercises** are an exercise you should try. These exercises are often used in prenatal exercises and to reduce incontinece, but you can use them too. The muscle serve a different function for women and various other functions for men. So don't be confused if you find a lot of information aimed at pregnant women or for older men.

I read about men that used these exercises and were very satisfied with the results.

[Kegel Exercise (Pelvic floor exercises)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kegel_exercise):

> Exercises are usually done to […] reduce premature ejaculatory occurrences in men, as well as to increase the size and intensity of erections.

While these exercises seem to make use of special devices, there are "body weight" style exercises too, that only aim on contracting the pelvic floor muscles.

You should also aim for a good overall fitness, using other exercises (cardio, resistance workouts, sports, …) and a healthy diet.

Comment: I've always understood that the special fitness of running helps all aspects sex related

Answer (score 8):

While there is no specific exercise that will do this general good aerobic conditioning will help. So, keep going to the gym and stay healthy and you should have long, happy sex for years to come.

From WebMD:

> The study showed that men over age 50 who kept physically active had a 30% lower risk of impotence than men who were inactive. As men age, the chance of impotence increases, but the research shows that exercise can keep a man going significantly longer. The findings appear in the August issue of Annals of Internal Medicine.
>
> Impotence Affects 20 Million Americans
>
> Studies show that impotence, also called erectile dysfunction, is far reaching; it affects as many as 20 million American men. By age 60 nearly half of all men will have had at least one brush with impotence, researchers say. For decades, worsening sexual function has been accepted as a natural part of aging, but researchers for this study write they may have proof this doesn't have to be the case.
>
> To test their theory, researchers surveyed more than 31,000 men between the ages of 53 and 90. Volunteers rated their ability in the previous three months, without treatment, to have and maintain an erection adequate for sex. Researchers also analyzed other measures of sexual function and looked at the men's lifestyle habits.
>
> Fitter Men Have Better Erections
>
> Results showed that men who were physically active reported better erections: The fitter the man, the better the erection. Frequent, vigorous exercise, the equivalent of running at least three hours a week or playing singles tennis five hours per week, produced the most benefit -- with a 30% lower risk of impotence.
>
> Findings also showed that men less than 60 years old benefited most from exercise. But bad lifestyle habits such as being overweight, watching more than 20 hours of television a week, and smoking offset the benefits of being young.
>
> Researchers write that they hope men will get an important message: Sexual activity can stay strong for years through healthy living. Impotence doesn't have to be a "normal" part of aging.
>
> SOURCE: Bacon, C. Annals of Internal Medicine, August 2003; vol 139: pp 161-168.
> WebMD: [Exercise Prolongs Men's Sex Lives](http://www.webmd.com/erectile-dysfunction/news/20030822/exercise-prolongs-mens-sex-lives)

Comment: Added info from WebMD

Comment: @jmort253 Fixed quoting. Thank you for the suggestion, should have done so from the start.